# What's the difference between using <img> and <canvas> for drawing images?

Tags: html, image, html5-canvas

I'm following the canvas tutorial on w3schools and I've just discovered that there is a canvas function for drawing images.

This is the example that I was looking at:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
};
```

Well ... sience I've always used the `<img>` tag for showing an image in my page I asked myself what was the difference between this two ways of showing images.

Any idea ?

Comment: Well sorry for the duplicate question ... can't erase it because I've got an answer, so sorry to all

Comment: it's expected you do a little searching / research before posting a question - a simple search for img vs canvas brings up all the dupes please remind yourself of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry for that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't, typically, use a canvas for displaying a single static image.

What you might do, is have a number of different image files, and compose on one canvas. For example, if you had images for "man" and "block" and "monster", and you rendered them onto a canvas 30 times a second, updating their relative positions based on, say, key events, then you've basically created a game.

If you just display a single static image, then there is no different from just using a `<img>` tag, and that is probably what you should do, because that makes it clearer what it is.

A `<canvas>` is for graphics you want to dynamically generate/manipulate using javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and teaching :)